# How to make the touchscreen go to sleep?

Tags: arduino

Hi so I have a Arduino mega 2560 with a Adafruit TFT touch shield, im using the tft library to write my things at the moment. I want to know if there is a function to turn off the screen (to save power), and then implement a physical button to turn it back on again? How do I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control the backlight directly out of the box.  Check out the link from the AdaFruit website:

[Controlling the Backlight](http://learn.adafruit.com/2-8-tft-touch-shield/controlling-the-backlight)

You will need to physically alter your TFT shield with a knife and soldering iron (but the soldering job should be easy).

As to using a physical button to wake it up -- yes.  And good news for you, since you are using a Mega, you can attach to an I/O pin!   (With a UNO, it would be more difficult).

So you can add a pushbutton switch to ground and set the pinMode to INPUT_PULLUP.